# ubuntu14.04,M2Crypto==0.25.1,openssl (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.22) run django get undefined symbol: SSLv2_method

Tags: python, openssl, dockerfile, m2crypto

> "docker build dockerfile when run 'python manage.py makemigrations'
>   get 'undefined symbol: SSLv2_method'"

1. Traceback (most recent call last):
             File "manage.py", line 10, in 
               execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
       line 353, in execute_from_command_line
               utility.execute()
             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
       line 327, in execute
               django.setup()

   ```
           apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
   line 115, in populate
           app_config.ready()
         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py",
   line 22, in ready
           self.module.autodiscover()
         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py",
   line 26, in autodiscover
           autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py",
   line 50, in autodiscover_modules
           import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
           __import__(name)
         File "/goldbox-backend/goldbox_p2p/admin.py", line 28, in <module>
           from goldbox_common.crypto import ReportCrypto
         File "/goldbox-backend/goldbox_common/crypto.py", line 5, in <module>
           from M2Crypto import RSA,BIO,EVP
         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/__init__.py", line
   26, in <module>
           from M2Crypto import (ASN1, AuthCookie, BIO, BN, DH, DSA, EVP, Engine, Err,
         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/ASN1.py", line 15,
   in <module>
           from M2Crypto import BIO, m2, util
         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/BIO.py", line 10, in <module>
           from M2Crypto import m2, util
         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/m2.py", line 30, in <module>
           from M2Crypto._m2crypto import *
         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/_m2crypto.py", line
   26, in <module>
           __m2crypto = swig_import_helper()
         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/_m2crypto.py", line
   22, in swig_import_helper
           _mod = imp.load_module('__m2crypto', fp, pathname, description)
       ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/__m2crypto.so:
   undefined symbol: SSLv2_method
   ```

how can i fix it?
thanks~

Comment: It looks like M2Crypto is importing `SSLv2_method`. That was mostly removed from OpenSSL last year (about 18 months ago) You should try to update M2Crypto to a [modern version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2Crypto). Also see [OpenSSL SSLv2_method missing](https://www.google.com/search?q=OpenSSL+SSLv2_method+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0):

Update to [the latest upstream version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2Crypto/0.26.0). If there is still problem when you follow [INSTALL](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/blob/master/INSTALL.rst), please file a new issue report in the upstream tracker. Thank you.